# Include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Cannot open source file "avr/interrupt.h"

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

Within Visual-Studio-Code, I was recieving the error in the title from `#include <Arduino.h>`. The files compile in the Arduino app.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, add the following paths to your `includePaths` in your `.vscode/c_cpp_properties`.

```
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/",
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/EEPROM/",
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SPI/",
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/",
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/",
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/",
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/",
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/compat/",
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/util/"
```